# Column "skipped" when opening file in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

When opening some shared files in Excel, some columns are "skipped". They are not hidden but they are not visible in the window.

For example, Column A is not visible. At first look, it seems that the file is starting at Column B. You always have to scroll left to see first column.

Why do we have this and how can this be changed? This is quite annoying because some users forget this and might miss some columns.

Comment: Open workbook. Scroll to left until column A become visible. Click on A1 cell to activate it. Save workbook. Close. Reopen - now column A must be visible. *Why do we have this* Visual layout is saved in workbook, If column A was out of visible border while save it will be "invisible" while reopen.

Comment: @JvdV Excel remembers precisely visual layout, not active cell only. You may test. Scroll to hide column A, select B1, save. Close and reopen - column A remains "invisible".

Comment: @JvdV Moreover, active cell may be out of screen (invisible) while save - while reopen it remains "invisible"! Screen layout is not adjusted for to show active cell...

Comment: @Akina, let me refrase my comment (indeed there is little relevance to an active cell's focus). If OP is looking into a VBA way that would open Excel at the start of the worksheet he could look into [this](https://superuser.com/questions/448845/how-to-make-excel-open-at-the-first-column-of-the-chart-instead-of-far-right) older answered question which makes use of `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView`.

Comment: That's it indeed. Thank you. One of you will write an answer?